# How to expose single modules of an Angular library through public-api.ts as of Angular 13?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I just upgraded an Angular library project from version 11 to 13, and got an error, when trying to run `ng build`.

At version 11, the setting was the following:

- I had several smaller modules, each consisting of several components, and directives
- each module was exposed from the `public-api.ts`
- the consumer UI was able to import each module where it was needed

So each modules would be simply

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AComponent],
  imports: [],
  exports: [AComponent],
})
export class AModule {}
```

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [BComponent],
  imports: [],
  exports: [BComponent],
})
export class BModule {}
```

And exposed from public-api.ts:

```
export { AModule } from './lib/acomponent/a.module';
export { BModule } from './lib/bcomponent/b.module';
```

This was working just fine with Angular 11, where I used ngcc for building the library. However, after upgrading to Angular 13 (where libraries are built with Ivy partial compilation mode by default), I got an error for the modules above:

```
error Unsupported private class AComponent. This class is visible to consumers via AModule -> AComponent, but is not exported from the top-level library entrypoint.

error Unsupported private class BComponent. This class is visible to consumers via BModule -> BComponent, but is not exported from the top-level library entrypoint.
```

So how to expose modules in an Angular library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to export the components through your public-api:

```
export { AModule } from './lib/acomponent/a.module';
export { AComponent } from './lib/acomponent/a.component';
export { BModule } from './lib/bcomponent/b.module';
export { BComponent } from './lib/bcomponent/b.component';
```

Comment: This actually works, but sounds like a workaround.

Comment: The component part was the piece that was missing for me.